# Factorize: $1-\frac{1}{6}z^{-1}-\frac{1}{3}z^{-2}$ into $(1-az^{-1})(1-bz^{-1})$

Tags: factoring, rational-numbers

Currently stuck with factorizing $1-\frac{1}{6}z^{-1}-\frac{1}{3}z^{-2}$ into $(1-az^{-1})(1-bz^{-1})$

How do I get there? I would like to know how to do it without guessing.

Tried pq, but got stuck with

z1=$-\frac{1}{12}+\sqrt{\frac{13}{36}}$

Thanks for any help. I am really struggling with factorizing in general. The formula is the denumerator of a rational function. So I am basically looking for zeros. Hence the try with pq.

Also applied it to the formula multiplied by $z^2$

Comment: You can either view this as a quadratic in $w=z^{-1}$ or multiply the LHS by $z^2$, factor, and then divide each of the two factors by $z$. I'd lean towards the latter as the formulas are perhaps a bit easier. You can also multiply by 6 to get integral coefficients since there's less chance of an arithmetic error that way; just divide your resulting factors appropriately.

Comment: Thanks @StevenStadnicki I will try this now!

Comment: Question: If I multiply by 6 I get $6z^2$ Can I apply the pq formula and divide the result by 6? Ahhhh damn! Thanks, I guess yes, because this would follow all rules of math. PQ just got way easier with this

Comment: I'm not sure what the 'pq' formula is precisely; you can always apply the classic quadratic formula. I _do_ get a term that has a rational square root, so I suspect your arithmetic is wrong somewhere.

Comment: $x^2+px+q$ and to get zeros: $\text{zero}_{1,2} =-\frac{p}{2} \pm \sqrt{ ( \frac{p}{2})^2-q}$

Comment: I got $\frac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{ \frac{9}{4} }$

Comment: Assuming that's correct, you can simplify $\sqrt{\frac94}$... :-)

Comment: I think it's not correct. I have a solution and it's 1/2 and -2/3  But now I got 2/6 and -1/6

Comment: What would be the way to handle it if ax^2+bx+c = 0 and and we ignore a and use b and c with this formula? Thought that it is possible to take the solution and divide it by a to get the solution for x^2+bx+c = 0

Comment: Update to my question a(x^2+b/a x+c/a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by $6z^2$: you get
$$
6z^2-z-2
$$
The roots are easily seen to be $2/3$ and $-1/2$, so the polynomial factors as
$$
6\Bigl(z-\frac{2}{3}\Bigr)\Bigl(z+\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)
$$
Divide back by $6z^2$ to get
$$
\Bigl(1-\frac{2}{3}z^{-1}\Bigr)\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{2}z^{-1}\Bigr)
$$

Comment: How do you get them, without easily seeing them? Shouldn't there be a way to get from your first formula to the second one by changing the equation?

Comment: @Rapiz I believe that anybody writing on this site should know the quadratic formula.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula ?

Comment: @Rapiz Yes, that's it.

Comment: Thanks, yes basically applied the simpler form with a=1. In Germany it's called pq-formula and we basically got teached this one. Didn't know the general formula. Thanks!

Comment: @Rapiz I wasn't aware of this. But it's just complicating things. Well, you're German…  Just joking…

Comment: Applied for the Diversity Lottery. So hopefully soon an American :D Have a good upcoming week! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an error inside the square root, p/2=-1/12 not -1/6

Comment: Ah! Thanks! $-\frac{1}{12}\pm \frac{7}{12}$